# How to create separate empty lists assigned to separate variables?

Tags: list-manipulation

Instead of doing

```
l1 = {}
l2 = {}
```

is there a way to incorporate a loop to make this process faster?

Comment: `l1 = l2 = {}`?

Answer (score 3):

Use an [`indexed variable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html)

```
Clear[x]

(x[#] = {}) & /@ Range[5];

x /@ Range[5]

(* {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to define and set symbols `x1..xn` to `{}`

```
Do[Evaluate@ToExpression["x" <> ToString@i] = {}, {i, 5}];
{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}
(* {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use array

```
l = Array[{}&, 5]
AppendTo[l[[1]], 5]
l
```

2. use SetDelayed, then you can have any l[n] :)

```
l[x_] := l[x] = {}
l[2]
l[4]
AppendTo[l[2], 5]
l[2]
```